# PYTHON3 | Parsing JSON | index out of range | can't access to 1st column of an array

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexoutofrangeexception

I have this JSON (I don't give you the whole thing because it's freaking long but you don't need the rest.)

```
cve" : {
 "data_type" : "CVE",
 "data_format" : "MITRE",
 "data_version" : "4.0",
 "CVE_data_meta" : {
   "ID" : "CVE-2018-9991",
   "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
 },
 "affects" : {
   "vendor" : {
     "vendor_data" : [ {
       "vendor_name" : "frog_cms_project",
       "product" : {
         "product_data" : [ {
           "product_name" : "frog_cms",
           "version" : {
             "version_data" : [ {
               "version_value" : "0.9.5"
             } ]
           }
         } ]
       }
     } ]
   }
 },
```

What I want to do is to print the vendor name of this cve.
So, what I did is :

```
with open("nvdcve-1.0-2018.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    increment = 0
    number_cve = data["CVE_data_numberOfCVEs"]
    while increment < int(number_cve):
        print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'])
        print (',')
        print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'])        
        print ("\n")
        increment +=
```

The reason I did a while is because in the JSON file, there is a lot of CVEs, this is why I did data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve'] (and this part works fine, the line    `print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'] is working well).

My error is in the `print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'])` line, python returns a list index out of range error.

But if I'm reading this JSON well, vendor_data is an array of 1 column so vendor_name is the ['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'] isn't it ?

The only way to parse the vendor_name i found is :

```
for value in data['CVE_Items'][a]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data']:
    print (value['vendor_name'])
```

instead of `print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'])`

And doing a for just for one iteration is pretty disgusting :s, but at least, value is the data['CVE_Items'][a]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0] that I wanted....

Anyone knows something about it ?

Comment: Are you sure every `CVE_Item` has an `vender_data`? Because if you use `for value in` and you come across one that's empty it ignores it. So that explains why that solution works

Comment: Oh I just see that I have 4337 vendor_data but only 3107 vendor_name. It can explain the thing yes. Thank you !

So, should I catch the exception and stay with the print method (not the for) ? I'm not really used with Pyhton.

I'm a bit disapointed that the error was just that .. :s

Comment: Yeah you could stay with selecting the `vendor_name` with `[0]`. So first check if it's not empty or the length of the array is greater than 0, then you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure every `CVE_Item` has an `vender_data`.

Example:

```
with open("nvdcve-1.0-2018.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    increment = 0
    number_cve = data["CVE_data_numberOfCVEs"]
    while increment < int(number_cve):
        print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'])
        print (',')
        if (len(data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data']) > 0) :
            print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'])        
        print ("\n")
        increment +=
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ron Nabuurs' answer i found that all my vendor_data does not always have a vendor_name. So it is why the for works and not the print.
(the for check if the object is non null, else it stops).

So what I did is :

```
            try:
                print (data['CVE_Items'][increment]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'])
                print (',')
            except:
                pass
```